# Cross Platform (Android & iOS) game engine for 2D with InApp-store

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, game-engine, phaser-framework

*Before we start: Yes, this question has been asked and answered for similar backgrounds a couple of times, but all extensive answers to this questions I could find are at least 2 years old and game engines come and go.
On top of that I have some specific requirements that I could not find being discussed in any of the posts.*

What I want to accomplish is to create a 2D game. I have a background in Java programming and programmedd some simple Android apps (a messenger and stuff like that). I also have very basic C++, C# and JavaScript knowledge as well as OpenGL and building an own 3D engine (university project):

- Should run on Android (version 5 or higher) and probably iOS (I haven't done anything with iOS yet so this will be my first project).
- Needs some very basic physics for bullets/hit-tests (I can also code this if it's necessary so this more like a soft constraint but I'd prefer the engine or some simple library to do the work for me)
- UI-components. Yes, I will need them and many will be text-oriented. Also scrollable components. I have seen many engines lacking these and coding it from scratch can be tedious. Also many engines make it hard to create more complex UIs which I would probably need.
- In-App purchases. It would be really nice if wouldn't have to mess around with this too much.
- Some nice graphic effects.. Parallax effects, particles (for magic spells, etc)
- Communication with a centralized game server.
- Notifications in the notification bar (with custom images and texts
- Should be able to handle basica animations, play music and videos.
- Should be able to integrate with Social media (Facebook and/or Twitter as a minimum). Would be nice to have something like "Like our page on Facebook to receive X coins).
- Performance is probably NOT critical - I assume that any game engine fullfilling the other requirements is programmed sanely enough to be fast enough on a modern device.
- Should be battle tested, not being abandoned, have a reasonable documentation and community
- Rapid development should be possible. This is very important to me as I plan to change the style and other things quite often and let people test and comment the changes.

What I found are basically some different types of engines:
 - Engines where one builds a game in a framework and manually adds native code for things the engine does not support, like LibGdx.
 - HTML5-only engines that need some 3rd party app-wrappers like phaser + CocoonJS. Some other also provide this, like Kiwi.js.
 - Monolithic engines that provide everything (okay only one: Unity).

From all of the engines I have seen I think Unity would fit my needs best, but then again I have no experience whatsoever with it.

What would you suggest?

Comment: This Q will get closed for for being off-topic (See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic off-topic bullet #4)  
However, to answer your Q anyway, yes, Unity is a great fit for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at [GameMaker: Studio](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker)

Here is course on Lynda [Learning GameMaker: Studio and GML](https://www.lynda.com/GameMaker-tutorials/Learning-GameMaker-Studio-GML/550749-2.html)